# Error in local windows when running supee-6788-toolbox

Tags: git, magento, patch

I am running commands of fixSupee6788 from https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox on local windows system (xampp) but when I run this command

```
php -f fixSUPEE6788.php -- analyze
```

after enetring into "shell" of my magento project in git bash I get:

```
sh.exe": php : command not found
```

Please let me know that where I need to run this or what I need to remove this?
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step, you should install PHP in your Operating System, and make sure that the PHP executable is in your %PATH%.

Comment: I have installed php at C:\xampp\php

Comment: Then make sure that your PHP executable is on the system's %PATH%.

Comment: please let me know that how can I do that.

Comment: Why don't you Google "add php to path in Windows"?

Comment: Cool. Could you please upvote and mark the answer as correct? (green check)

Comment: Interesting it worked for you. If you look at this thread: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14052/applying-php-5-4-support-patch-for-magento-ce-1-7-in-a-windows-environment and my response I ALWAYS have to do what I said in my response there.